# Using PHP/openssl to securly exchange business data

Tags: php, openssl

I want to exchange data with other businesses using PHP/OpenSSL. Each business creates public/private keys and publishes the public key. Then, I write code to manage all that. Here is a code in PHP (mostly from php.net):

```
<?php
$data = "secret message";

$key = file_get_contents("bus1.pub");

// get temp file w/ write access
$plaintextfile  = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'abc');
$ciphertextfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'abc');

$fp = fopen($plaintextfile, "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

// encrypt it
if (openssl_pkcs7_encrypt($plaintextfile, $ciphertextfile, $key,
    array("To" => "nighthawk@example.com", // keyed syntax
          "From: HQ <hq@example.com>", // indexed syntax
          "Subject" => "Eyes only"))) {
   echo "encryption ok<br>";
} else
        echo "failure<br>";

?>
```

However, I get an error (failure). I suspect that I do not generate the keys correctly using OpenSSL. Please help in how to properly generate the keys so that they can be read by PHP functions above.

This is what I tried:

```
openssl genrsa  -out bus1.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in bus1.pem -pubout > bus1.pub
```

Comment: What does `openssl_error_string()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php)) return when you have a failure?

Comment: with openssl_error_string(), I get: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Comment: The public file looks like: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvoefJiWjf0Gwg0MVrYp4
...deleted a few lines for clarity ...
ipm/AVKC+gbZBj55LK6IT3RBDxey1apa59GOADqLW7hZhE+XziKnbIUTqJgu1bmf
mQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured out the mistake. Thanks to @towr for pointing out a debugging tool. For other readers, the solution is to generate the certificate as follows. Each business need to do this, keep the private key and publish the certificate:

```
openssl genrsa  -out business1.pass.key 2048
openssl rsa -in business1.pass.key -out business1.key
openssl req -new -key business1.key -out business1.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in business1.csr -signkey business1.key -out business1.crt
```

Comment: Which one of these is the public key?

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion from php docs `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php`.

This Is The Most Secure Way To Encrypt And Decrypt Your Data,
It Is Almost Impossible To Crack Your Encryption.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--- Create Two Random Keys And Save Them In Your Configuration File ---

<?php
// Create The First Key
echo base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));

// Create The Second Key
echo base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));
?>
--------------------------------------------------------
<?php
// Save The Keys In Your Configuration File
define('FIRSTKEY','Lk5Uz3slx3BrAghS1aaW5AYgWZRV0tIX5eI0yPchFz4=');
define('SECONDKEY','EZ44mFi3TlAey1b2w4Y7lVDuqO+SRxGXsa7nctnr/JmMrA2vN6EJhrvdVZbxaQs5jpSe34X3ejFK/o9+Y5c83w==');
?>
--------------------------------------------------------
<?php
function secured_encrypt($data)
{
$first_key = base64_decode(FIRSTKEY);
$second_key = base64_decode(SECONDKEY);   
   
$method = "aes-256-cbc";   
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_length);
       
$first_encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data,$method,$first_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA ,$iv);   
$second_encrypted = hash_hmac('sha3-512', $first_encrypted, $second_key, TRUE);
           
$output = base64_encode($iv.$second_encrypted.$first_encrypted);   
return $output;       
}
?>
--------------------------------------------------------
<?php
function secured_decrypt($input)
{
$first_key = base64_decode(FIRSTKEY);
$second_key = base64_decode(SECONDKEY);           
$mix = base64_decode($input);
       
$method = "aes-256-cbc";   
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
           
$iv = substr($mix,0,$iv_length);
$second_encrypted = substr($mix,$iv_length,64);
$first_encrypted = substr($mix,$iv_length+64);
           
$data = openssl_decrypt($first_encrypted,$method,$first_key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);
$second_encrypted_new = hash_hmac('sha3-512', $first_encrypted, $second_key, TRUE);
   
if (hash_equals($second_encrypted,$second_encrypted_new))
return $data;
   
return false;
}
?>
```